# Resource file in cocoapod is set to a wrong target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a public CocoaPod called [CountrySelectorView](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CountrySelectorView). It's basically a small library that allows users to select countries from a list. This list of countries is included as a json file in the pod.

I released the first version (v0.1.0) a few months ago and it worked well without an issue. Today I added some new changes to the codebase and released a new version (v0.1.2).

When I install this new version now, the countries.json file is assigned a weird target.

[image]

And this affects only that json file. All other files are set to the proper target.

[image]

This is my podspec file. The only thing I changed here was the version string before publishing the new version. No changes were done to the countries.json file either apart from some minor content changes.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'CountrySelectorView'
  s.version          = '0.1.2'
  s.summary          = 'CountrySelectorView lets users pick a country from a list.'

  s.description      = <<-DESC
                        CountrySelectorView lets users pick a country. You can show it either as a list where you can search or a picker view.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/CountrySelectorView'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Isuru-Nanayakkara' => '<my_email>' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/CountrySelectorView.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'

  s.source_files = 'CountrySelectorView/Classes/**/*'
  
  s.resource_bundles = {
      'CountrySelectorView' => ['CountrySelectorView/Assets/countries.json']
  }

  s.frameworks = 'UIKit'
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
end
```

Strange thing is when I install the old version (v0.1.0) now, this problem arises in that version as well! Prior to today, it worked fine.

Any idea what may have caused this?

[Demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpnx61w2kzxldv1/countrydemo.zip?dl=0)